# Visual Studio 2005 crashes when modifying any file or project property

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Ok, this one is a bit bizarre.  If I modify ANY property in the file or project properties dialog, Visual Studio 2005 crashes.  Right-click file or project, select Properties, change anything => goes boom.  Happens with both C++ and C# projects (haven't tried any other project types).  I don't have any add-ins installed and it happens both with existing and new projects.  I haven't installed any new hardware or drivers recently; the only changes I'm aware of are upgrading Chrome, Firefox (and plugins), and a Windows update for time zones; doesn't seem likely any of those would cause this.  I've tried running with /safemode and /resetskippkgs command line options and neither helped.  I would like to avoid a reinstall if possible as VS2005 is particularly painful in that regard.  Anyone seen anything like this?  My google-fu was not strong.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

Event Viewer has the following:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3623 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A0BC58E) (80131506)

Using my google-fu I eventually came across [KB963676](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963676) and [KB981574](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981574).  Unfortunately, the available [hotfix](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=33154) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured I would try to [repair the .NET Framework 2.0 framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/02/18/9432938.aspx) (this MUST be done from a command line) before trying anything more drastic.  Lo and behold, it worked!  Perhaps someone else will run into this and find this question.